# HashSet usage with int arrays

Tags: java, hashset

As I have an ArrayList of int arrays which contains duplicates, I'd like to use HashSet. Unfortunately, I can't manage to use HashSet as I wish:

```
System.out.print("\nTESTs\n");
    ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    list.add(new int[]{1,2,3});
    list.add(new int[]{5,1,1});
    list.add(new int[]{1,2,3});//duplicate
    list.add(new int[]{5,1,3});

    Set<int[]> set = new HashSet<int[]>(list);
    System.out.println("Size of the set = "+set.size());

    ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<int[]>(set);
    System.out.println("Size of the arrayList = "+arrayList.size());

    for (int[] array:arrayList){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
```

It results in:

```
Size of the set = 4
Size of the arrayList = 4
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] // duplicate still here
[5, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 3]
```

Could anybody tell me where I'm wrong ?

Thanks in advance
Dominique (java newbie)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Arrays don't override `hashCode` and `equals` implemented in `Object` class, and therefore, two arrays a1 and a2 will be considered as identical to each other by `HashSet` only if a1==a2, which is false in your case.

If you use `ArrayList`s instead of arrays, your problem will be solved, since for `ArrayList`s equality is determined by the equality of the members of the lists (and the order in which they appear).

Answer (score 5):

That's because `HashSet` uses `.equals()` to see if a new object is duplicated (and `.hashCode()` to determine the "bucket").

When you work with arrays, please be aware that `new int[]{1,2,3}` is NOT "equal to" `new int[]{1,2,3}`.

The proper way to "deep compare" arrays is via `Arrays.equals(a, b)` method.

To solve your problem situation effectively you should create a wrapper class which contains your `int[]` array and then implement `.hashCode()` and `equals()` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add each number *individually*. Don't add `Arrays to HashSet`

```
    int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
    int[] arr2 = {1,2,3};
    System.out.println(arr1==arr2);//false
    System.out.println(arr1.equals(arr2)); //false
```

Two arrays with same values need not be `equal` (they use *default* `equals()` method defined in `Object` which compares *references*.)