# HashSet doesn't fill with elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have a HashSet declared and want to fill it with an array which is also declared. But when I want to fill it with the elements of the array it doens't work. I already tried to make a output where a text is standing in. The problem is, even the text doesn't appear in the output. I cant find my mistake.
Here is the part of the program which makes troubles

```
public void part8(){
        HashSet<Book> set = new HashSet<Book>();
        Iterator iter = set.iterator();

        //put array into hashset
        for ( int i = 0; i < set.size(); i ++){
            System.out.println("Test");
            set.add(book[i]);
        }

        //print hashset
        System.out.println("Ausgeben der HashSet");
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(set);
        }

        //add a duplicate, which shouldn't be shown in the output
        set.add(book[5]);

        //try to show the hashset after adding duplicate
        System.out.println("Ausgeben der HashSet nach hinzufügen des Duplikats");
        System.out.println(set);

        //TreeSet
        TreeSet<Book> ts = new TreeSet<Book>();

        //hmake treeset from hashset
        ts.addAll(set);

        //print treeset
        System.out.println("Ausgeben der TreeSet");
        System.out.println(ts);
    }
```

thank you guys for help.

Comment: You should iterate over `book.length` not over `set.size`. As you have just declared it, and not inserted any objects, it is empty, so the for never executes.

Comment: "*But when I want to fill it with the elements of the array it doens't work.*" - What does "*doesn't work*" mean? Problems are expected since [Arrays do not overwrite the `hashCode()`-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344312/hashset-usage-with-int-arrays)

Comment: thank you very much Shirkman now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this part:

```
    //put array into hashset
    for ( int i = 0; i < set.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Test");
        set.add(book[i]);
    }
```

to

```
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(book));
```

and all the elements in the array will be correclty added...

ps...

You should also change this part:

```
    //print hashset
    System.out.println("Ausgeben der HashSet");
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(set);
    }
```

to something like

```
for(final Book book: set){
    System.out.println(book);
}
```

in order to correclty print each book contained in the set....

Answer (score 2):

As for this code, there are a few things wrong:

```
//put array into hashset
for ( int i = 0; i < set.size(); i ++){
    System.out.println("Test");
    set.add(book[i]);
}
```

This loop will never execute as the set `size` is 0. You should change `set.size()` to `book.length`.

```
//print hashset
System.out.println("Ausgeben der HashSet");
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

I suposse that here you want to print `set` content. Instead doing that, you should replace loop content by:

```
Book book = iter.next();
System.out.println(book.toString()); //Print whatever you want
```

**EDIT:** As @Lucas Oliveira says, you also can insert every member of the array in the set by: `set.addAll(Arrays.asList(book));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in following code:

```
    //put array into hashset
    for ( int i = 0; i < book.length; i ++){
        System.out.println("Test");
        set.add(book[i]);
    }
```

**Because** you have created a new `HashSet<>` in line `HashSet<Book> set = new HashSet<Book>();`. Since it is just created and no `element` is inserted yet, hence the call `set.size()` will return `0` and hence there will be no iteration of `for-loop`'s body.

Corrected code is as following:

```
    //put array into hashset
    for ( int i = 0; i < set.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Test");
        set.add(book[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you iterate with an empty set !

replace :

```
    //put array into hashset
    for ( int i = 0; i < set.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Test");
        set.add(book[i]);
    }
```

with :

```
    //put array into hashset
    for ( int i = 0; i < book.length; i ++){
        System.out.println("Test");
        set.add(book[i]);
    }
```

or :

```
    //put array into hashset
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(book));
```